# How to display loading message when waiting for asp.net to return to a new view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searched this a lot on the internet and I am looking for a way in where to display a loading message while asp.net is moving from one page to another. I have tried the load method from JavaScript but it does not work for moving from one page to another so how can I do this when a search button is clicked.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <section class="search-sec">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <input type="text" name="searchTitle" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Job Title, Skills, Company!">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <input type="text" name="searchLocation" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Location">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-danger wrn-btn">Search</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

}
```

Comment: are you loading pages with ajax? If not, what you want is not possible.

Comment: You can't add a loading screen when you redirect to other pages. Why not just use ajax instead so you won't need to redirect?

Comment: How would that be possible what I am doing is that I have the home page in where the user inputs the details and than clicks search the system will redirect the user to new page but there is a waiting time before redirecting so I would like to display something to warn the user that its just the system taking time to display the result is that not possible. No I am not using ajax because I am moving from the main page to the result page

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ajax then you could load the new page with a loading message and remove it when the load is complete. I used this one in one of my projects (https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-css3-spinning-preloader/). Basically you activate or deactivate adding a class to the html body.

In the view where I want to show it before anything else i put this:

```
<script>
     $('body').removeClass('loaded');
</script>
```

and once everything is loaded :

```
<script>

    //...other stuff

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('body').addClass('loaded');
        }, 500);

    });

</script>
```

But you would still have time of wait before reaching the page, you should capture the search click and show the loader **before** leaving the first page.

Anyways I agree with Jerdine and daremachine, you would have more control loading with ajax the search results and showing them in the same page. Maybe is not possible so I hope the workaround works for you